# How to use file descriptions in cobol?

Tags: cobol

I have seen in some of the tutorials that the records are declared only in file description(FD) and in some tutorials they have declared the record in Working storage section and used it.What is the difference between the both.
In some programs it is like this

```
FD STUDENT
01 FS-EMP-REC.
   02 FS-EMP-ID            PIC X(07).
   02 FS-EMP-NAME          PIC X(20).
   02 FS-EMP-ACCT          PIC X(06).
01 WS-EMP-REC.
   02 WS-EMP-ID            PIC X(07).
   02 WS-EMP-NAME          PIC X(20).
   02 WS-EMP-ACCT          PIC X(06).
```

In some tutorials it is (FD alone)

```
01 FS-EMP-REC.
   02 FS-EMP-ID            PIC X(07).
   02 FS-EMP-NAME          PIC X(20).
   02 FS-EMP-ACCT          PIC X(06).
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a question of coding style. Some people just always use `READ ... INTO ...` or do a MOVE of the `01` under the `FD` to an `01` in the `WORKING-STORAGE`. Often the `01` in the `FILE SECTION` will just be defined with an elementary FILLER to describe the length of the input record.

Sometimes there is a specific need to do this, if the particular COBOL being used limits the use of the data in the FD (in Enterprise COBOL you can't SET an address for something in the `FILE SECTION`, and DB2 requires a known address, so can't be in the `FILE SECTION`, for instance).

People tend to think it is "safer" to use the `WORKING-STORAGE`, but this is not the case. People also think it easier to locate information in the `WORKING-STORAGE`when a program fails.

The `READ ... INTO ...` requires an extra transfer of the data, so will be "slower", but that is only a problem in extreme situations.

You'll see both in programs, as you already have done, and there is no hard-and-fast answer as to why one program uses on, and another the other. Mostly it will just make no difference at all.

With `READ ... INTO ...` the record will still also be available in the `FILE SECTION`.

Unless necessary, I don't use `READ ... INTO ...` myself, but many people think programs won't work properly if you don't use it :-)

Just be aware of the two different ways, and use the way that those you are coding with use.